# Needing To Move WooCommerce Category Title Below Subcategories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Please see [this website](http://cox.digitaloft.co.uk/product-category/model/honda-accord/). 
This is still in development but there is an issue. To reflect the design which was done, we need to move the `HONDA ACCORD PARTS` which is `woocommerce_page_title` to sit below the subcategories yet above the `category description`.

We managed to move the description below using:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 100 );
```

We have tried to override the WooCommerce templates but this does not work. This has been put together on the Ultimatum framework (understood that this isn't the best option but I didn't develop it and it's not up for discussion to change at the moment) and it seems that however we try to over-ride, it doesn't work.

I've even tried editing the `/archive-product.php` in the plugin folder itself to test. This does NOT work.

Any help is appreciated ... it's a must that this is done and I'm losing the will to live trying to sort it!

Comment: Kindly, it's difficult to understand, what you want exactly. when i go to your web site i see **HONDA ACCORD PARTS** in main page title (i suppose that this is the one you want to unset (hide or remove)). I see it also in the as a title `<h1>` in **terms description** block (I suppose you want to keep this one), is that right? Are actually the `remove_action` and `add_action` active? *(Please, may be you can add a screenshot with what you want)*. Do you want that behavior on all woocommerce pages?